# Swift color-set programatically - Return color based on device color mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to achieve the Xcode color-set programatically. Get the colour based on theme

```
var appThemeColor : Any {
    if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        return UIColor.DarkTheme.self
    } else {
        return UIColor.LightTheme.self
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    
    struct LightTheme {
        static let barDeselectedColor =  UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        static let appBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    struct DarkTheme {
        static let barDeselectedColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        static let appBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
    }
}


class MainVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = appThemeColor.appBackground
    }
}
```

Depending on the device color mode. should return the color

> view.backgroundColor = appThemeColor.appBackground

how ever my implementation is not working as expected. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Why not set different colors direct from the ```.xcassets```?

Comment: "... is not working as expected", this is very vague. _What_ isn't working as expected and _how_ is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of simpler ways to do this;

You can define your colours using the [`dynamic provider initialiser`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init):

```
struct MyTheme {
    
    private func isDark(_ traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> Bool {
        return traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
    }

    public var barDeselectedColor = UIColor { (traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
        return self.isDark(traitCollection) ? UIColor(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1) : UIColor(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
    }

    /// etc
}
```

Then use it like

```
    self.someBar.backgroundColor = MyTheme().barDeselectedColor
```

The system will supply the current trait collection to your initialiser and you will get the correct color back.

Or you can add your colours to your asset catalog as dynamic colours and refer to them by name.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply assign the color to your label or view background using your color set
add a color set in your **Assets.xcassets** name your color set e.g **primary_color** and set color value
then use as you need e.g

```
self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "primary_color")
```

or

```
self.yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "primary_color")
```

no need to check either mobile them is on dark mode or light this color set handle automatically the color you set in color set